# Conditional Probability of a variables given five independent variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have six independent variables A, B, C, D, E and F and I would like to compute the conditional probability of A given B, C, D, E and F.  To illustrate the problem, is this answer correct?
P(A|B,C,D,E,F) = P(A|B)*P(A|C)*P(A|D)*P(A|E)*P(A|F)

Comment: Is this an assignment for a course? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Conditionally independent _given_ **what?** And what do _you_ understand (math formula please) by "$X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$."

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity